# Neo4j: Take intersection of two MATCHs

Tags: neo4j, intersection

I have the two following queries:

```
MATCH (s1: location)-[:SHIPS_TO]->(: midLocation)-[: LEAVES]->(d1: location)
RETURN s1.name, count(d1)
```

```
MATCH (s2: location)-[:SHIPS_TO]->(: midLocation)-[: LEAVES]->(d2: location)
WHERE s2.manager = d2.manager 
RETURN s2.name, count(d2)
```

And what I would like to do is return the intersection of these two queries. What I am really trying to do is find all the locations that ONLY ship to locations with the same manager (where shipping locations are separated by a single 'midLocation' node), and the finding the intersection of the two lists would accomplish this, but I can't seem to find a way to implement it. Maybe this is another way to do it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the queries are the same except you added `WHERE s2.manager = d2.manager` in the last one? If so then the intersection of the two would just be the results of the 2nd query.

Comment: No, sorry. I want a list of all the locations, which ONLY ship to locations with the same manager. So the query would just count the number of locations where this condition holds. For example, if one location, loc1, shipped to 4 places, 3 of which had the same manager, then the first query would return "loc1: 4", and the second query would return "loc1: 3". The intersection would then be all the ALL places the location shipped to had the same manager.  I would only want to return the location if both queries had the same count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a collection of predicates you can check that they are all true using `all`, so you could do

```
MATCH (s1: location)-[:SHIPS_TO]->(: midLocation)-[: LEAVES]->(d1: location)
WITH s1, collect(DISTINCT d1) AS destinations
WHERE all(d IN destinations WHERE d.manager = s1.manager)
RETURN s1.name, size(destinations)
```

This will filter out any source locations that have managers that are different from their destinations.
Note that this is not optimal since you still find every location pair before checking if they have the same manager. It would be better to find a way to have the first match statement fail as soon as a destination was found with a different manager, but I don't think that is possible in pure Cypher.

Comment: Thank you! This does indeed return the correct locations! But when I run it it says d1 is not defined?

Comment: Right, that's the last line that there was an error in. `d1` is no longer defined since it's not carried on from the with statement. I have edited in a fix.